# Protractor - action between specs in suite

Tags: protractor, angularjs-e2e, test-suite

I've created few tests (Specs) in Protractor - that every test works fine when running alone. the problem is that when executing them as one suite - the tests break. 
I'd like to add some operation in between the tests - such as timeout or logout. 
is there an option to do it?
I've tried looking here:
https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js

this is my conf.js file (the specs part):

```
suites:{
    sanity: ['*/AccountSettingsTest.js','*/createApptest.js']

},

specs: ['*/AccountSettingsTest.js'],
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use jasmine `afterAll` function. It should run after the describe block in your test. Just your logout/timeout function into an `afterAll` block inside of your `describe` block, and for that spec file, it will run after the describe. Since you have multiple specs, I imagine you'll want it in each spec file, as the order the files run in may vary.

From the [jasmine docs](http://jasmine.github.io/2.1/introduction.html):

```
describe("A spec using beforeAll and afterAll", function() {
  var foo;

  beforeAll(function() {
      foo = 1;
  });

  afterAll(function() {
      foo = 0;
  });

  it("sets the initial value of foo before specs run", function() {
      expect(foo).toEqual(1);
      foo += 1;
  });

  it("does not reset foo between specs", function() {
      expect(foo).toEqual(2);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed try to add the below line in your **conf.js** file to restart your browser between tests -

```
restartBrowserBetweenTests: false,
```

In order to keep a default timeout add below line in **jasmineNodeOpts** object -

```
defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000
```

A detailed explanation is given in the [referenceConf.js file](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/referenceConf.js)

Comment: @user2880391 , can you please clarify the problem you are facing if the above answer isnt the one you are looking for.